# Phonegap Facebook authentice in server side using expressjs and passportjs

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, passport-facebook

I built a web server using nodejs and expressjs where authentication is done using passportjs.
I now want to build a mobile application using phonegap and of course use my existing web server to query for data. 
I need to authenticate my users using Facebook connect on my server and only then the session is created and I can query my API.
I searched a lot for a solution and found nothing. I looked at InAppBrowser and ChildBrowser but I don't think they will do the trick as I need to keep the session alive in order to query the api.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks